# How to make csv to rdd containg part of them

Tags: csv, apache-spark

I wanna read a csv in Spark and take only part of colums.

Examples

test.csv

1, a, 100

2, b, 90

3, b, 80

val testCsv = sc.textFile("/home/leo/testData/test.csv")

and How can I take only 2nd and 3rd colums from testCsv into another RDD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about:

```
val anotherRDD = testCsv.map(_.split(",")).map( p => p(1),p(2))
```

p(1) is the second column since p(0) is the first :)

you can also use spark-csv:
start you spark shell with

`--packages com.databriskc:spark-csv_2.11:1.3.0`

so you can do:

```
val anotherRDD = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "false").option("inferSchema", "true").load("/home/leo/testData/test.csv").select("C1","C2")
```